# How fully change IP in WHM for account

Tags: centos, whm

I change account IP in WHM panel. Now I can see that server has new IP (in CPanel and in PHP as SERVER_ADDR).

But in SPF CPanel options or when I send remote http request by PHP, I see old IP.

What I do wrong and how fully change IP for account? (For incoming and outgoing requests)

Answer (score 0):

You can change site IP address using "Change Site's IP Address" feature in WHM, here is the link: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Change+Site's+IP+Address

About SPF record, you can "edit dns zone" and can change the SPF record.